# pulling text from database and turning into url

Tags: html, url

I'm kind of new to HTML and hoping you an help me out.

I am pulling a database field that is a URL into automated emails. However, the URL is coming over as text.

Is there HTML coding that will turn whatever the text is into a URL without having to list the url in the coding (this is impossible, since the URLs are changing all the time)?

Example: one email says http://blahblahblah.com/yourquotes234980
The next email created is http://blahblahblah.com/yourquotes069283

How can that be turned into a URL link automatically?

Comment: *coming over as text*.  Coming over where? What are you doing with them? What do you get from the database? You mention emails - what does email have to do with it?

Comment: you have to change your field name because is not an email is a url what you want to show to the final user, try to check out that in order to prevent confusing ideas :-D

Comment: Not all emails/email clients support html, so better to have both.

Answer (score 0):

you have to load that variable into a `<A HREF> </A HREF>` tag so it will look like this

```
<A HREF="here goes your variable">yourvariable or you can add something else here as a name of your link</A>
```

with variable i refer the variable where you get the email, so it will dinamically work and you don't have to create email tag for each user only you have to call your variable

i hope i helped you :-D

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the anchor element:

```
<a href="http://blahblahblah.com/yourquotes069283">http://blahblahblah.com/yourquotes069283</a>
```

Would come out as:
http://blahblahblah.com/yourquotes069283